# Image upload to folder by not DB

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, mysqli, server-side

I have created a script in order for a person to upload both text information and a picture to a DB. The picture is hosted in a subfolder to the website called "images".

The problem that I am facing is that the folder is being uploaded to the folder, but the file name is not being recorded in the db.

I know it isn't a connection problem because the text fields are being recorded in the db while the file name is being left as a blank.

I think it probably is an issue with my checkUpload() method.

Here is my script in totality

```
<?php
printForm();
//when "submit" tie together values and variables
if($_POST['submit']=="Submit"){
    $email = cleanData($_POST['email']);
    $first = cleanData($_POST['first']);
    $last = cleanData($_POST['last']);
    $status = cleanData($_POST['status']);
    //$image = cleanData($_POST['image']);
    //echo "Data cleaned";
    addData($email, $first, $last, $status);
}
else{
    //printForm();
}


function checkUpload(){
    //check for uploaded files
    if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){ //upload refers to form element "upload"
        $allowed = array ('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/GIF');
        if(in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $allowed)){//if upload if in the allowed array 'file types'
            echo "uploading files...";
            //move the file over
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "images/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")){
                //moveuf method moves to tmp folder then moves to final location
                echo "<p>The file has been uploaded 'dude'</p>";
                $image="{$_FILES['upload']['name']}";

            }//end of moving DAT IMG :3
            else{
                echo '<p>Please upload a  JPEG, GIF or PNG image.<strong>';


                if($FILES['upload']['error'] > 0){
                echo '<b>The file could not be updated because</b>';
                switch($_FILES['upload']['error']){//standard error casee
                    case 1:
                        echo 'The file exceeds the upload_max_filesize setting in php.ini';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        echo 'The file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE in the HTML form.';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        echo 'The file only partially uploaded';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        echo 'The no file was uploaded';
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        echo 'No temporary folder was available';
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        echo 'Unable to write to the disk';
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        echo 'File upload stopped';
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo 'A system error occurred';
                        break;
                    }
                echo '</strong></p>';
                }
                //if the file is still in the temporary folder "unlink" which is basically just deleting the SOB
                if(file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])){
                    echo 'File exists! :D';
                    unlink ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
                }
                return $image;
                //gives back image where the function was called
            }
        }
    }
}


//cleans information
function cleanData($data){
    if(!$status){ //everything except for status take out spaces
        $data = trim($data);
    }
    $data = stripslashes($data);//no slashes
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);//no special characters
    $data = strip_tags($data);//no html tags
    return $data;
}

//inserts data into db
function addData($email, $first, $last, $status){
    //echo "Ready to add data";
    include("dbinfo.php");//access db
    $image = checkUpload();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(null, '$email', '$first', '$last', '$status', '$image')";
    //null because of ID aka primary key automatically incremented:3
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    //takes sql arugment for query OR if it can't you get a BUMMER DUDE
    echo <<<HERE
    <b>The following has been added:</b>
    <ul>
    <li>E-mail: $email</li>
    <li>First: $first</li>
    <li>Last: $last</li>
    <li>Status: $status</li>
    <li>Image File:<br/> <img src="images/$image" /></li>
    </ul>

HERE;

}

function printForm(){
    $pageTitle ="Add a Contact";
    include("header.php");
    echo <<<EOD

        <b>Add a Contact</b>
        <form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="first">First Name*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first" id="first" required="required">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="last">Last Name*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last" id="last" required="required">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="status">Status*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="status" id="status" required="required">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="image">Image*:</label>
            <input type="file" name="upload" size="30" id="upload" required="required"><br/>
            <small>Must be less than 512kb. Only JPG, GIF, and PNG files</small>
        </div>

        <div id="mySubmit">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
        </form>
EOD;
}

include("footer.php");
?>
```

Also-- as a side note, in my last post I was informed that mysql has been succeeded by mysqli.I've noticed almost exact syntax in some of the functions where I can just add an i to the end of "mysql"; however, in some functions, this is not the case. if I were to use the same mysql functions however, change them to mysqli, is there any significant changes I'd have to make to the script?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of $image after you done the upload? You also have an error in your code:   if($FILES['upload']['error'] > 0){ should be   if($_FILES['upload']['error'] > 0){

Comment: I'm not sure now, but shouldn't a file name be stored in $_FILES['upload']['name'] instead of $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] ?

Besides, this should throw an error (notice):
function cleanData($data){
    if(!$status){

Your $status variable is not available in this scope, nor it's declared as global.

Consider setting: display_errors = On; setting in your php.ini to see where you do mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need a big re-factoring. But in order to make it work move the following block code to the where `move_uploaded_file` returns `true` and return null when it returns false

`if(file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])){
                    echo 'File exists! :D';
                    unlink ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
                }
                return $image;
                //gives back image where the function was called`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but wouldn't it be more constructive to tell me what I should rework rather than "a big re-factoring"?
thanks.

Comment: also, this did not make a difference.  :/